# What is the relation between Iterable and Iterator?

Tags: scala, iterator

What is the difference between `Iterator` and `Iterable` in scala?

I thought that `Iterable` represents a set that I can iterate through, and `Iterator` is a "pointer" to one of the items in the iterable set.

However, `Iterator` has functions like `forEach`, `map`, `foldLeft`. It can be converted to `Iterable` via `toIterable`. And, for example, `scala.io.Source.getLines` returns `Iterator`, not `Iterable`.

But I cannot do `groupBy` on `Iterator` and I can do it on `Iterable`.

So, what's the relation between those two, `Iterator` and `Iterable`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In short: An `Iterator` does have state, whereas an `Iterable` does not.

See the API docs for both.

[Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html):

> A base trait for iterable collections.
>
> This is a base trait for all Scala collections that define an iterator
>   method to step through one-by-one the collection's elements.
>   [...] This trait implements Iterable's foreach method by stepping
>   through all elements using iterator.

[Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html):

> Iterators are data structures that allow to iterate over a sequence of
>   elements. They have a hasNext method for checking if there is a next
>   element available, and a next method which returns the next element
>   and discards it from the iterator.
>
> An iterator is mutable: most operations on it change its state. While
>   it is often used to iterate through the elements of a collection, it
>   can also be used without being backed by any collection (see
>   constructors on the companion object).

With an `Iterator` you can stop an iteration and continue it later if you want. If you try to do this with an `Iterable` it will begin from the head again:

```
scala> val iterable: Iterable[Int] = 1 to 4
iterable: Iterable[Int] = Range(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> iterable.take(2)
res8: Iterable[Int] = Range(1, 2)

scala> iterable.take(2)
res9: Iterable[Int] = Range(1, 2)

scala> val iterator = iterable.iterator
iterator: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next
res23: AnyVal = 1

scala> if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next
res24: AnyVal = 2

scala> if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next
res25: AnyVal = 3

scala> if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next
res26: AnyVal = 4

scala> if (iterator.hasNext) iterator.next
res27: AnyVal = ()
```

Note, that I didn't use `take` on `Iterator`. The reason for this is that it is tricky to use. `hasNext` and `next` are the only two methods that are guaranteed to work as expected on `Iterator`. See the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html) again:

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise,
>   one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. The two
>   most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: next and
>   hasNext.
>
> Both these methods can be called any number of times without having to
>   discard the iterator. Note that even hasNext may cause mutation --
>   such as when iterating from an input stream, where it will block until
>   the stream is closed or some input becomes available.
>
> Consider this example for safe and unsafe use:
>
> ```
> def f[A](it: Iterator[A]) = {
>   if (it.hasNext) {            // Safe to reuse "it" after "hasNext"
>     it.next                    // Safe to reuse "it" after "next"
>     val remainder = it.drop(2) // it is *not* safe to use "it" again after this line!
>     remainder.take(2)          // it is *not* safe to use "remainder" after this line!
>   } else it
> }
> ```

Comment: Odersky and Spoon wrote a good primer on the Scala collection classes: see
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Comment: I have tested this in Scala 2.11.7, iterator behaves similarly to iterable, namely, when you invoke `take(2)` for the second time, you still get `List(1, 2)`.

Comment: @qed Thanks for your comment, my answer was partly incorrect. You are not allowed to call `take` multiple times on the iterator. I edited my answer and mentioned this.

Comment: What does "one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it" actually mean? One should call a method on a iterator only once? An iterator would be useless under such conditions.

Comment: @qed You can call `hasNext` as often as you want and `next` as long as `hasNext` returns true. All other methods can only be called once and return a new iterator. On this newly introduced iterator, another method can be called but not on the first iterator. I think it is not the best design on how the iterators should work but I don't know what led to these design decisions.

Answer (score 7):

Another explanation from Martin Odersky and Lex Spoon:

> There's an important difference between the foreach method on
>   iterators and the same method on traversable collections: When called
>   to an iterator, foreach will leave the iterator at its end when it is
>   done. So calling next again on the same iterator will fail with a
>   NoSuchElementException. By contrast, when called on on a collection,
>   foreach leaves the number of elements in the collection unchanged
>   (unless the passed function adds to removes elements, but this is
>   discouraged, because it may lead to surprising results).

Source: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html

Note also (thanks to Wei-Ching Lin for this tip) `Iterator` extends the `TraversableOnce` trait while `Iterable` doesn't.