# Scala List of tuple becomes empty after for loop

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I have a Scala list of tuples, "params", which are of size 28. I want to loop through and print each element of the list, however, nothing is printed out. After finishing the for loop, I checked the size of the list, which now becomes 0.

I am new to scala and I could not figure this out after a long time googling.

```
val primes = List(11, 13, 17, 19, 2, 3, 5, 7)
val params = primes.combinations(2)
println(params.size)

for (param <- params) {
  print(param(0), param(1))
}
println(params.size)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`combinations` methods in List create an `Iterator`. Once the `Iterator` is consumed using methods like `size`, it will be empty.

From the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html)

> one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it.

If you comment out `println(params.size)`, you can see that for loop is printing out the elements, but the last `println(params.size)` will remain as 0.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you know how I can save the result from combination methods to use for later?

Comment: @HoaTrinh, `combination(n).toList` will serve the purpose. Remember though, this will only create a `List[List[Int]]` and not `List[(Int, Int)]` as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Johny's great answer:

> Do you know how I can save the result from combination methods to use for later?

Well, as already suggested you can just `toList`
However, note there is a reason why `combinations` returns an `Iterator` and it is because the data can be too big, if you are okay with that then go ahead; but you may still take advantage of laziness.

For example, let's convert the inner lists into a tuples before collecting the results:

```scala
val params =
  primes
    .combinations(2)
    .collect {
      case a :: b :: Nil => (a, b)
    }.toList
```

In the same way, you may add extra steps in the chain like another `map` or a `filter` before doing the `toList`
Even better, if your end action is something like `foreach(foo)` then you do not even need to collect everything into a `List`

Answer (score 1):

`primes.combinations(2)` returns Iterator.

> Iterators are data structures that allow to iterate over a sequence of
> elements. They have a hasNext method for checking if there is a next
> element available, and a next method which returns the next element
> and discards it from the iterator.

So, it is like pointer to Iterable collection. Once you have done iteration you no longer will be able to iterate again.

When `println(params.size)` executed that time iteration completed while computing `size` and now params is pointing to end. Because of this `for (param <- params)` will be equivalent looping around empty collection.

There can 2 possible solution:

1. Don't check the size before for loop.
2. Convert iterator to Iterable e.g. list.
   `params = primes.combinations(2).toList`

To learn more about Iterator and Iterable refer [What is the relation between Iterable and Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302270/what-is-the-relation-between-iterable-and-iterator)